# An event for focus changed?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm porting my Visual Basic 6 program to PyQt.

I need to call a function to set some widget enable/disable all the time, I don't want to call a function too many times, so I found a event, when the focus is changed from a widget to another widget, I can call my widget manager function.

I'm looking for the same thing in PyQt but without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signal [`QApplication::focusChanged(QWidget * old, QWidget * now)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#focusChanged) is what you want.

Comment: Yes, it is! But I have to connect the signal outside of the window() class. Sounds Very strange? What should contain in the class and what should contain outside of class?

Answer (score 12):

Not sure whether you are talking about the widget's window gaining/losing focus or a widget embedded in another gaining/losing keyboard focus, but here's for both situations

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowActivate:
            print "widget window has gained focus"
        elif event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            print "widget window has lost focus"
        elif event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
            print "widget has gained keyboard focus"
        elif event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            print "widget has lost keyboard focus"


        return False
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understand what is a widget. It is not a windows in my opinion, but this a object in a window (like a button, or a grid, etc)

Comment: in qt even a qmainwindow is a widget. By default a widget may have its own window, or be embedded in its parent's window(unless it's a qdialog). To test this, create a qpushbutton without a parent and then `show()` it, it will have its own window. All this being said, my code still shows how to get notified if and when your widget receives keyboard focus

Comment: also, I didn't say that a widget is a window, in my answer I said "...widget's window...", what I was talking about there was a parent widget which is displayed in its own window, like a qmainwindow or qdialog or qwizard, all of which inherit directly or indirectly from qwidget

Comment: Thanks. In wxWidgets, all objects in a window called widgets, and the window is called frame. Now I'm understood the Qt way.

Comment: However, `eventFilter()` is a good feature and I didn't know it before your answer. Upvoted!